# Conversion of if-else statement of mule3 to mule4

Tags: mule, dataweave, mule4

How to convert below mule3 code to mule4:

```
#[validateCurrentQuarter ? false: (year == prevQuarterYear) &&  (month == prevQuarterMonth)]
```

Comment: what are validateCurrentQuarter, year, prevQuarterYear, month and prevQuarterMonth exactly? what types and values have?

Comment: hi @aled, all these are variables

Comment: usually variable is Mule 3 are prefixed with `flowVars.` And what are their data types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Mule 4 the expression language is [DataWeave 2.0](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dataweave-language-guide). The equivalent of the ternary operator is if/else. Variables must be prefixed with `vars.`. Assuming vars.validateCurrentQuarter is boolean:

```
#[if (vars.validateCurrentQuarter) false else (year == prevQuarterYear and month == prevQuarterMonth)]
```

You can find more information in the [migration guide](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.4/migration-mel).